# PostSharp exception stack trace is not complete

Tags: postsharp

In the below code, args.Exception.ToString() (or args.Exception.StackTrace) returns only the method name and line where the exception is thrown but not the complete call stack.

```
  public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Logger.GetLogger().Write(LogLevel.Error,  args.Exception.ToString());            
    }
```

But the below code gives the complete callstack

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

How can I get the full call stack in PostSharp with MethodExecutionArgs?

Comment: What version of PostSharp do you use? It works well in 5.0.32. Did you try `Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());` in `OnException`? Maybe the problem is logger related (stack trace is multiline).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with PostSharp but with my code. I had applied [SwallowException] on the whole assembly instead of at the caller.
Also, Logger.GetLogger().Write() supports multiline. 
Thanks Jakub.